# Simulating parallel calls to a method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I have a method which is frequently called from different users so I want to simulate this behavior in order to observe it's behavior

I've read about `fork` and `threads` and actually think that `fork` is better suited for this purpose but I couldn't get anywhere with `fork` so I switch to `threads` and I got this:

```
module MethodBenchmark
  extend self

  def execute_with_threads
    arr = []
    3.times do |i|
      arr[i] = Thread.new {
      puts "Thread number #{i}"
      call_actual_method(3)
    }
    end
    arr.each {|t| t.join;}
  end

  def call_actual_method(number_of_requests)
    number_of_requests.times do |i|
      puts "Executing request #{i}"
    end
  end

end
```

the result I got is

```
Thread number 2
Executing request 0
Executing request 1
Executing request 2
Thread number 0
Executing request 0
Executing request 1
Executing request 2
Thread number 1
Executing request 0
Executing request 1
Executing request 2
```

So what I want is each thread to represent a different user and each request, well to represent a new request from a random user. In other words I would like to have an output something like this:

```
Thread number 2
Executing request 0
Executing request 1
Thread number 0
Executing request 2
Executing request 0
Executing request 1
Thread number 1
Executing request 2
Executing request 0
Executing request 1
Executing request 2
```

The idea being that once all the threads have spawned I'll get a lot of concurrent requests from different threads and not that sequential output. How can I achieve this behavior?

*P.S* 
I hoped that this could be due to the small amount of threads/requests but I got the same sequential result with 25 threads and 100 requests per thread.

*PS.PS*
Inside the body of this method
    def call_actual_method(number_of_requests)

I plan to actually call a method which is making request to the database

def call_actual_method(number_of_requests)
    number_of_requests.times do |i|
      method_to_call_database()
    end
   end

Currently `method_to_call_database()` has two possible implementations in terms of how the `SQL` is structured and I want to measure the execution time of both implementations under a given load. The idea is to choose the faster method.

Comment: You can't control this. The threads *are* running like you expect, but each thread is finishing so quickly that you can't really tell. Try sleeping for a random duration inside your loop.

Comment: @meagar I see. You are right. After adding some delay I got the random output I was expecting. Do you think this i a valid way to test for concurrent issues?

Comment: No, I personally wouldn't bother with this approach.

Comment: @meagar Could you share your thought on what is a better way to simulate concurrent calls to a method and measure the time. Currently I have 2 different implementations and I want to figure out which one will have better performance.

Comment: @Leron would you provide more context to what exactly you are trying to test as a result of your users' interaction?

Comment: @MihailPanayotov I've added a `PS.PS` :) Could it be we are colleagues? :)